# How to obatin a thread ID in the range (0,MaxDegreeOfParallelism) in a parallel.for

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to assign and index in the range (0 to MaxDegreeOfParallelism) to each incoming thread in a parallel.for. I have tried using CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId and CurrentThread.Name but they are not in a given range and think they sometimes change values (is this right?). What I am using now is a  ConcurrentStack in the following way which works but I think is making my loop horribly slow.  Any idea how I could solve this problem? Thanks!!

```
    int nCPU = 16;  //number of CORES
    ConcurrentStack<int> cs = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nCPU; i++) { cs.Push(i); }

    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = nCPU - 1;
    Parallel.For(0, 10000, options, tt =>
    {
        int threadIndex;
        cs.TryPop(out threadIndex); //assign an index to the incoming thread

        //..... do stuff with all my variables matrix1[threadIndex][i][j], matrix2.......//

        cs.Push(threadIndex);  //the thread leaves the previously assigned index 
    });
```

Comment: Considering that it's the *max* degree of parallelism, not the *absolute* degree of parallelism, it seems to me that `matrix1[15]`, for example, will be worked on far less than the other indexes. Could you explain what you're trying to do with this matrix? It seems like you're trying to split up the load, but the elements being worked on will not be properly distributed.

Comment: thanks!, It is for doing independent fire simulations in parallel. Matrix[threadIndex][i][j] (with threadIndex from 0 to the number of cpus) represent a blank 2D raster(i,j)  where a single thread does all the computations and where the final solution is return (the arrival time of the fire at each cell). In this set up I dont mind if matrix[15][i][j] doesnt get used too much (which i agree with you it will not), but about being able to assign a free threadindex (an index not used by any thread between 0 and cpu) to every new thread entering the parallel loop.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, it might make sense to run: `Parallel.For(0, nCPU, options, tt => { for (var i = 0; i < 10000/nCPU; i++) //Do stuff with matrix1[tt], matrix2[tt].. etc })`. Depending on how variably intensive your work is, this may perform better

Comment: yes !!!!, that looks like is going to solve my problem. THANKS!!!.  ;)  still, it is funny that there is not a direct way to get the threadid in a for loop.

Comment: No worries. It's also possible you may find more luck using localised buckets (check out the overloads of `Parallel.For`). You *can* get a thread ID, but that's not going to help with assigning to an index. Since it's running in parallel, it wouldn't make *that* much sense to be given a thread ID in sequential order (especially since they're coming from a pool - we're not guaranteed to only have 15 threads - we could have 100 threads - we're only guaranteed to have a maximum of 15 threads at one time).